# Sum elements of array that have the same keys

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3

I have an object array that looks like this:

```
[{"SerialNo":"38","Name":"Client X","CounterDate":"2015-12-12","CursUSD":"3.91","M1":"29007","M2":"142109","M3":"403","M4":"383","M5":"171116"},
 {"SerialNo":"38","Name":"Client X","CounterDate":"2015-11-11","CursUSD":"3.85","M1":"26605","M2":"126979","M3":"370","M4":"360","M5":"153584"},
 {"SerialNo":"69","Name":"Client X2","CounterDate":"2015-12-11","CursUSD":"3.90","M1":"6","M2":"7","M3":"8","M4":"9","M5":"10"},
 {"SerialNo":"69","Name":"Client X2","CounterDate":"2015-12-09","CursUSD":"3.88","M1":"1","M2":"2","M3":"3","M4":"4","M5":"5"}
 {"SerialNo":"89","Name":"Client X3","CounterDate":"2015-12-09","CursUSD":"3.88","M1":"1","M2":"2","M3":"3","M4":"4","M5":"5"}]
```

I trying to combine the sub arrays that have the same SerialNo. The data is almost always in pairs. If not, it's just the line and it should be kept. (like Client X3)

The output I need is like this:

```
[{"SerialNo":"38","Name":"Client X","CounterDate":"2015-12-12","CursUSD":"3.91","M1":"2402","M2":"15130","M3":"33","M4":"23","M5":"17532"},
 {"SerialNo":"69","Name":"Client X2","CounterDate":"2015-12-11","CursUSD":"3.90","M1":"5","M2":"5","M3":"5","M4":"5","M5":"5"},
 {"SerialNo":"89","Name":"Client X3","CounterDate":"2015-12-09","CursUSD":"3.88","M1":"1","M2":"2","M3":"3","M4":"4","M5":"5"}]
```

So the SerialNo and Name are kept, CounterDate and CursUSD are the ones from the first line  encounter, M1.firstline - M1.secondline, M2.firstline - M2.secondline ...

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I only found answers for multidimensional arrays so not really helpful

Comment: Are you being lazy to iterate?

Comment: You don't need to find an answer.. you must try it by yourself.. otherwise you will not learn anything..

Comment: Well I'm not sure how to compare the first object with the second one. I know I can do a foreach but after that ...

Comment: It seems like it could be done with reduce in php http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);

$result = array_reduce($array, function ($result, $item) {
    if (!isset($result[$item['SerialNo']])) {
        $result[$item['SerialNo']] = $item;
    } else {
        $result[$item['SerialNo']]['M1'] += $item['M1'];
        $result[$item['SerialNo']]['M2'] += $item['M2'];
        $result[$item['SerialNo']]['M3'] += $item['M3'];
        $result[$item['SerialNo']]['M4'] += $item['M4'];
        $result[$item['SerialNo']]['M5'] += $item['M5'];
    }
    return $result;
}, array());

var_dump(json_encode($result));
```